# Why std::u16string is slower than array of char16_t?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, c++11, stl

After some performance experiments, it seemed that using char16_t arrays may boost performance sometimes up to 40-50%, but it seems that using std::u16string without any copying and allocations should be as fast as C arrays. However, benchmarks are showing the opposite.

Here is the code I've written for benchmark (it uses Google Benchmark lib):

```
#include "benchmark/benchmark.h"
#include <string>

static std::u16string str;
static char16_t *str2;

static void BM_Strings(benchmark::State &state) {
    while (state.KeepRunning()) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(str[i]);
        }
    }
}

static void BM_CharArray(benchmark::State &state) {
    while (state.KeepRunning()) {
        for (size_t  i = 0; i < str.size(); i++){
            benchmark::DoNotOptimize(str2[i]);
        }
    }
}

BENCHMARK(BM_Strings);
BENCHMARK(BM_CharArray);

static void init(){
    str = u"Various applications of randomness have led to the development of several different methods ";
    str2 = (char16_t *) str.c_str();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    init();
    ::benchmark::Initialize(&argc, argv);
    ::benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks();
}
```

It shows the following result:

```
Run on (8 X 2200 MHz CPU s)
2017-07-11 23:05:57
Benchmark             Time           CPU Iterations
---------------------------------------------------
BM_Strings         1832 ns       1830 ns     365938
BM_CharArray        928 ns        926 ns     712577
```

I'm using clang (Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)) on mac. With optimizations turned on the gap is smaller but still noticeable:

```
 Benchmark             Time           CPU Iterations
---------------------------------------------------
BM_Strings          242 ns        241 ns    2906615
BM_CharArray        161 ns        161 ns    4552165
```

Can someone explain what's going on here and why there is a difference?

Updated (mixing the order and added few warm-up steps):

```
Benchmark             Time           CPU Iterations
---------------------------------------------------
BM_CharArray        670 ns        665 ns     903168
BM_Strings          856 ns        854 ns     817776
BM_CharArray        166 ns        166 ns    4369997
BM_Strings          225 ns        225 ns    3149521
```

Also including compile flags I'm using:

```
/usr/bin/clang++ -I{some includes here} -O3 -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -Wall -Wextra -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -O3 -fsanitize=address -Werror -o CMakeFiles/BenchmarkString.dir/BenchmarkString.cpp.o -c test/benchmarks/BenchmarkString.cpp
```

Comment: Which compiler flags are you using for the optimized build?

Comment: First result with -O0 - no optimizations, second - with -Ofast

Comment: Do you get compatible results if you change the order of the benchmarks? Also, you should ignore any benchmark with `-O0`.

Comment: look at the generated code

Comment: Please include all compiler flags used *in the question itself*.  Performance data without that is useless.

Comment: I've updated description with more tests (opposite order)

Comment: clang doesn't have an 8.1 version.  I suspect you are using XCode 8.3 which in turn uses "Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)"?  Or "Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)"?

Comment: Ooops sorry, yep you're right: it's Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)

Comment: Don't see why you expect to get similar performance when you go to great lengths to avoid optimizations. C++ abstractions tend to melt away only completely when you optimize completely... So @MarAldorasi's answe is not surprising.

Comment: @einpoklum: it is perfectly valid to expect the same performance. If string didn't use SSO, it would have the same performance. If string had a different design, then instead of SSO, it could use reference counting, so this example would run at the same speed (of course, then something else would be slower, which is fast currently, it would be a different trade-off)

Comment: @geza I read your comment as: "If [things that may or may not happen under the hood] it would have the same performance." `std::string` can do all sort of magic. Until C++11 you couldn't even trust it to have contiguous storage IIANM.

Comment: Why in the world do you put the *critical part of the benchmark* in `benchmark::DoNotOptimize`? This seems like a troll. All you're testing otherwise is the speed at which a `for` loop can iterate? Pointless! Voting to close as nonsense.

Comment: @CodyGray if so, why performance is different? From Google benchmark's manual: DoNotOptimize(<expr>) forces the result of <expr> to be stored in either memory or a register.

Comment: What do you mean "if so"? Marc already explained why there's a performance difference in this case. What doesn't make sense to me is what you thought this benchmark was supposed to test, and why you wrote it to disable optimizations (clobber global memory) in the critical part of the function.

Comment: What do you mean by disabling optimizations? You are saying that if I would use an output from [] operator to prevent compiler from throwing this operation away the result will be different than just calling DoNotOptimize?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because of the way libc++ implements the small string optimization, on every dereference it needs to check whether the string contents are stored in the string object itself or on the heap.  Because the indexing is wrapped in `benchmark::DoNotOptimize`, it needs to perform this check every time a character is accessed.  When accessing the string data via a pointer the data is always external, and so requires no check.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly I am unable to reproduce your results. I can barely detect a difference between the two.

The (incomplete) code I used is shown here:

```
hol::StdTimer timer;

using index_type = std::size_t;

index_type const N = 100'000'000;
index_type const SIZE = 1024;

static std::u16string s16;
static char16_t const* p16;

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(s16), SIZE,
        []{ return (char)hol::random_number((int)'A', (int)'Z'); });

    p16 = s16.c_str();
    unsigned sum;

    {
        sum = 0;

        timer.start();
        for(index_type n = 0; n < N; ++n)
            for(index_type i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
                sum += s16[i];
        timer.stop();

        RESULT("string", sum, timer);
    }

    {
        sum = 0;

        timer.start();
        for(std::size_t n = 0; n < N; ++n)
            for(std::size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
                sum += p16[i];
        timer.stop();

        RESULT("array ", sum, timer);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
string: (670240768) 17.575232 secs
array : (670240768) 17.546145 secs
```

**Compiler:**

```
GCC 7.1 
g++ -std=c++14 -march=native -O3 -D NDEBUG
```

Comment: Not surprising. libstdc++'s SSO uses a different design from libc++'s.

Comment: In libstdc++, there is always a pointer for the string. In clang's version, pointer exists only if it is a long string. So an `if` needed to get the pointer.

Comment: @T.C. I was thinking that predictive branch optimization would take care of `SSO` checks (in a tight loop). But looking at the source code I'm not even sure if `GCC` implements `SSO`, it seems to just yield a straight pointer...

Answer (score 0):

In pure char16_t you access array directly, while in string you have overloaded operator[]

```
reference
operator[](size_type __pos)
{
    #ifdef _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC
    __glibcxx_check_subscript(__pos);
#else
    // as an extension v3 allows s[s.size()] when s is non-const.
    _GLIBCXX_DEBUG_VERIFY(__pos <= this->size(),
        _M_message(__gnu_debug::__msg_subscript_oob)
        ._M_sequence(*this, "this")
        ._M_integer(__pos, "__pos")
        ._M_integer(this->size(), "size"));
#endif
    return _M_base()[__pos];
}
```

and _M_base() is:

```
_Base& _M_base() { return *this; }
```

Now, my guesses are that either:

1. _M_base() might not get inlined and than you get performance hit because of every read takes additional operation to read the function address.

or

2. One of those subscript checks happen.